# pagination, next page with scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy, request, screen-scraping

the next page button doesn't change the url when it's pressed, so i have problem with scrapy.

'''

```
import scrapy

class LegonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "legon"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://mylegion.org/PersonifyEbusiness/Find-a-Post",
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # Select distance and country
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='aspnetForm',
            formdata={'dnn$ctr2802$DNNWebControlContainer$ctl00$DistanceList': '100',
                      '@IP_COUNTRY': 'USA',
                      '@IP_DEPARTMENT': '00000000001L'},
            callback=self.parse_post_page
        )
    def parse_post_page(self, response):
        # Extract and yield requests for post detail pages
        post_elements = response.xpath("//div[@class='membership-dir-result-item']")
        for post_element in post_elements:
            post_num = post_element.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'POST_NAME')]/text()").get().strip()
            post_link = post_element.xpath("./a/@href").get()
            yield response.follow(post_link, callback=self.parse_post_detail, meta={'post_num': post_num})


        next_page_button = response.xpath("/input[@id='dnn_ctr2802_DNNWebControlContainer_ctl00_Next']")
        if next_page_button:

        # Extract form data for next page submission
            formdata = {
                '__EVENTTARGET': 'dnn$ctr2802$DNNWebControlContainer$ctl00$Next',
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': ''
                }
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=formdata, callback=self.parse_post_page)
        
    def parse_post_detail(self,response):
        leader1 = response.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'Leadership')]/div[2]/text())[1]").get()
        leader2 = response.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'Leadership')]/div[2]/text())[2]").get()
        address = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Address')]/div[2]/text()").get()
        typ = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Type')]/div[2]/text()").get()

        yield {
            "post_num": response.meta['post_num'],
            "leader1": leader1,
            "leader2": leader2,
            "address": address,
            "type" : typ

        }
```

i think scrapy didn't even go the next page he's going to the base url which is not changing at all when i press next page or i try to use new search method .

Comment: The pagination is done via POST request, you'll need to recreate it. You can use [BurpSuite](https://portswigger.net/burp) and send the first request and the pagination request to the comparer to see the differences in the requests.

Comment: i did what you told me, but i don't unerstand what should i do, i've downloded the BurbSuite and compared the differences in the requests, but i don't know what should i do in scrapy .

Comment: Please see my answer. If you have any questions please ask and I'll try my best to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I checked the responses I saw that I get the same page over and over.

If we use BurpSuite to inspect the requests and compare them we can see this part:
[image: BurpSuite comparer]

You can see on the RHS the the value "Next", but if we inspect the form data in the response we can see that the value is missing. We just need to add it:

```py
import scrapy


class LegonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "legon"

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://mylegion.org/PersonifyEbusiness/Find-a-Post",
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        # Select distance and country
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formid='aspnetForm',
            formdata={'dnn$ctr2802$DNNWebControlContainer$ctl00$DistanceList': '100',
                      '@IP_COUNTRY': 'USA',
                      '@IP_DEPARTMENT': '00000000001L'},
            callback=self.parse_post_page
        )

    def parse_post_page(self, response):
        post_elements = response.xpath("//div[@class='membership-dir-result-item']")
        for post_element in post_elements:
            post_num = post_element.xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'POST_NAME')]/text()").get().strip()
            post_link = post_element.xpath("./a/@href").get()
            yield response.follow(post_link, callback=self.parse_post_detail, meta={'post_num': post_num})

        next_page_button = response.xpath("//input[@id='dnn_ctr2802_DNNWebControlContainer_ctl00_Next']")
        if next_page_button:
            form_data = {'dnn$ctr2802$DNNWebControlContainer$ctl00$Next': 'Next'}
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata=form_data, callback=self.parse_post_page)

    def parse_post_detail(self, response):
        leader1 = response.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'Leadership')]/div[2]/text())[1]").get()
        leader2 = response.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'Leadership')]/div[2]/text())[2]").get()
        address = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Address')]/div[2]/text()").get()
        typ = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'Type')]/div[2]/text()").get()

        yield {
            "post_num": response.meta['post_num'],
            "leader1": leader1,
            "leader2": leader2,
            "address": address,
            "type": typ
        }
```

See the differences between my form data and yours.

BTW you missed a `/` in the selector of `next_page_button`.